# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resource' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to retrieve the last 4 results from craigslist using a query. I'm able to retrieve all of the information except for the URL of the image from the result, instead it loads one image and spits out Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resource' of undefined. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
This is the line that retrieves the image URL of the item: `data.query.results.item[i].enclosure.resource`

```js
function getRSSFeed(feed){
 // Build the YQL query
 var qryRSS = 'select * from rss where url='+'"'+feed+'"';
 // Initiate the YQL query
 $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
   {
     // settings API call
     q: qryRSS,
     format: "json"
   },
   function(data) {
     for (i=0; i<4; i++)
       {
       // Output a link, using the link attribute and the title attribute
       $('body').append('<a href="'+data.query.results.item[i].link+'">'+data.query.results.item[i].title+'<img src="'+data.query.results.item[i].enclosure.resource+'"></a>');
       // Output the description, using the description attribute.
       $('body').append(data.query.results.item[i].description);
     }
 });
  };
  getRSSFeed('https://swmi.craigslist.org/search/sss?format=rss&query=grand%20prix');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to create a function and verify if enclosure is not undefined. Here are the full example:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function getRSSFeed(feed){
        // Build the YQL query
        var qryRSS = 'select * from rss where url='+'"'+feed+'"';
        // Initiate the YQL query
        $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
          {
            // settings API call
            q: qryRSS,
            format: "json"
          },
          function(data) {
            for (i=0; i<4; i++)
              {
              // Output a link, using the link attribute and the title attribute
              $('body').append('<a href="'+data.query.results.item[i].link+'">'+data.query.results.item[i].title+mountImg(data.query.results.item[i].enclosure)+'</a>');
              // Output the description, using the description attribute.
              $('body').append(data.query.results.item[i].description);
            }
        });
        };

        function mountImg(enclosure){
          if(typeof enclosure !== 'undefined')
            return '<img src="'+enclosure.resource+'" />';
        }
        getRSSFeed('https://swmi.craigslist.org/search/sss?format=rss&query=grand%20prix');    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked! Was this because enclosure was trying to be accessed before it was retrieved? Just curious why it worked.

Comment: Hahahaha I really do not know, because I had to mount your example in a fresh HTML page. The really important think is, it is working, lol